# Oracle Trigger If statement condition not being met somehow?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

Thanks for reading. I'm currently working on a database of about 10 entities for a hypothetical store. The main entity is therefore Customer_Order and the purpose of this trigger is to check that the Customer's post code is not null when ever a row is inserted or updated in Customer_order. If it is null, the trigger should throw a warning.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Check_Order  
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Customer_Order 
for each row
DECLARE ShipAddress customer.ship_address.post_code%TYPE;
BEGIN 
IF (ShipAddress = '') then 
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20103, 'Shipping Address is empty');
END IF;
END; 
. 
run
```

---

I know there's no "Else", but I don't have any other actions other than to update the table which it does.
Don't worry about ShipAddress, I've tried this with simpler attributes and it simply does not trigger. All that happens is that the row will be inserted or updated, so it's not meeting the condition. I've tried all sorts, like "if(Payment_No='PAYM0001') which doesn't work, either. Is it because I'm using for each instead of a Statement level trigger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle silently converts empty strings (i.e. strings with the length zero) to NULL. So there never will be an `''` value in your column. Therefor the IF statement never is true. You need to check for NULL in that trigger:

```
IF (ShipAddress IS NULL) then 
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20103, 'Shipping Address is empty');
END IF;
```

But you should really, really follow Ben's advice and simply declare that column as NOT NULL, instead of using a trigger to check that.

**Edit**

You can do the not null check with a check constraint on your table:

```
 CREATE TABLE FOO
 (
    shipping_address ship_addres,
    CONSTRAINT check_post_code CHECK (shipping_address.post_code IS NOT NULL)
 )
```

Comment: Ah I see. I couldn't actually figure out how to declare it as not null as I created a type called addressType. In my system, all customers and employees (subtypes of "Person") inherit the addressType which contains its own various values, and I could never figure out how to actually set them as NOT NULL without making an object table. If you know of a way I'd appreciate it if you could take the time to share it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MoMoosa: see my edit for an example no how to declare a attribute of your type not null

Answer (score 1):

Oracle uses 3 value logic, null being the 3rd value. Something can either be true, false or non-existent. `null` is non-existence, which equals nothing. You can't test for null with an equality operator. Use `IF :new.ShipAddress is null` to test for nulls.

You're also referencing the column incorrectly in the trigger. There's no need to declare anything and you have to reference the `:new` or `:old` value. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_co.htm) is a good resource.

It would be better to disallow nulls by putting a constraint on the table so `shipaddress` can never be null. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_co.htm). So,

```
alter table my_table modify shipaddress not null;
```

to add it to the table in place. It's better to add the constraint when creating the table though. Doing this will also speed things up, slightly, because you don't need to evaluate the trigger.

**EDIT:**

`shipaddress` has the ring of being a full address, perhaps comma delimited? I would definitely recommend having each part of the address separated out so something like, `address1`, `address2`, `address3`, `town`, `county`, `postcode`. I'm British so change to `state`, `zip` etc as necessary. This makes querying and manipulation of the data, should you need to do it much, much easier.

Comment: Thank you, I've altered the table and that works very well. I should have explained about the shipAddress, it's of addressType which contains town, county, and postcode as well as a streetType that contains the street and number - probably unnecessary in hindsight - which works out okay. I totally agree though, I've seen other students who are just having single string lines for the address, so  at least I'm getting this part right. Thanks very much for your help!